# Computationnal Geometry Package & "Nontensor object generated" in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, compiler-errors, convex-hull

Each time i compute the ConvexHullArea of a set of points, I get the following :

```
CompiledFunction::cflist: Nontensor object generated; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>
```

The output seems correct

Is it normal ?

Is there a way to solve this problem ? To mute it permanently ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does `Off[CompiledFunction::cflist]` mute it? I am not sure why you are getting it, I don't; can you give an example?

Comment: Id does mute it, I will try to isolate the problem, the lists are to large to give the example here, i have to find when the problem appears !